# Download csv button in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm new to ruby and am having trouble creating a download csv button. I have the following code in my controller:

```
@csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
end
```

And I've made the button in my view:

```
<%= link_to "View CSV" %>
```

How do I get the @csv_string to download when the "View CSV" button is clicked? 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `send_data` after **@csv_string** declaration
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data

```
def show
  ...
  send_data @csv_string, filename: "something.csv"
end
```

also update `link_to` to use this action ie:

`<%= link_to "View CSV", show_path %>`

Comment: This works great but now whenever I enter the page the csv downloads. How do I change it so the csv only downloads when the button is clicked? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: use different action other than `show` then you are good to go, make sure you update `link_to` href as well